# Debugging in Borland C++ builder version 6.0

Tags: debugging, ide, c++builder, c++builder-6

I just wanted to know how to see the debugger window using this
software. So that I could see the flow of the code during run time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have C++ Builder installed then it all happens there with your source code. If you can see you source code you can debug it. Click in the left margin to set a breakpoint, press Run and hey presto you are debugging.

Comment: ld like to know how to set breakpoints in command mode. lm using notepad++ for make little test in console programs. thanks.